# Sniffing PS/2 communications

Tags: keyboard

I've got a new laptop, with a keyboard that has an Fn key. I've always believed Fn keys were handled in hardware by the keyboard, but in this instance, some things have triggered a doubt in my mind.

If it was an external keyboard, I'd hook it to a logic analyzer and be done with it. But I'd rather not do that on the brand new laptop.

Is there a way to somehow sniff PS2 communications? PS/2 being a serial protocol, I'd just like to get a dump of what's sent over the interface, ideally with timestamp.

(Just to be clear, I don't want to get what's being sent to apps, I want the as raw as possible data sent from the keyboard.)

Comment: Sure modern laptop keyboards use ps2? (this is a sincere question)

Comment: Yes. I suppose, ease. Laptop also has a touchpad over I²C bus... From the top of my head, most of my laptops had PS/2 keyboards. There's a lot of advantage to having a USB keyboard on a desktop computer. On a laptop, that's a lot more arguable ;)